# Using NOT, MIN, AND in SQL having clause creating error

Tags: sql, ingres

I am working on Ingres9.2 version. When I execute a query like

```
select col1 from table1 group by col1 having not((5=min(col1)) and (0 = 1))
```

it raising an error as:

> bad select or subselect target list has been found.

But the error not occurring if I change the query with any one of following conditions:
0=0 or 1=1 instead of 0=1.
Removing not.
Using or instead of and.
Removing min.

I am not able to find the reason for this behaviour. And the same error not occurring in other database which is also in Ingres. If anyone knows the reason, please explain it.

Comment: I don't know if it is allowed to do `min(col1)` when you are aggregating by that column.  In any case, neither `min(col1)` nor `0 = 1` make sense or seem to be useful.  Maybe tell us what your query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I have some tables on which I applied join based in some columns then in having I included some conditions like mentioned in above query for select

Comment: Ingres 9.2 is quite an old version. I can confirm your query works ok in Ingres 11.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ingres is an old database.  Maybe it has a problem with using an aggregation function on a `group by` key.  This is speculation, but this should work:

```
select col1
from table1 
where not (5 = col1) and (0 = 1))
group by col1 ;
```

Of course, the condition would be more likely written as `col1 <> 5`, but the two forms are equivalent.